# Substring each line of the string

Tags: php, string, substring

inside my `$result` variable i have a 5 line string:

0100014746510106200140001020061780000000041666670072860103508101
0100008030950106200270002020139450000000020000006663540105338500
0100004586400106200270002020206660000000003700000511890102603900
0100008204530106200270002020218320000000011666670014450101008906
0100015309660106200270002021023010000000019400001666460105319807

how can i `substr()` each line... in order to have this result:

010001 
010000 
010000 
010000 
010001

in only need to get the first 6 columns of each line... please help...

PHP code:

```
$file = 'upload/filter.txt';
$searchfor = $_POST['search'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$btn = $_POST['button'];


if($btn == 'GENERATE' ) {

//prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
//header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$filename.".txt ");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");


// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
 $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";


 // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
 if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
 $result = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
 echo $result;


  }

else{
 echo "No matches found";
 }

}
```

Comment: explode on line break then loop

Comment: @Bongsky . If you want to split (explode) a string into an array using a newline as separator, explode() is NOT the tool to use. refer my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
$str = "0100014746510106200140001020061780000000041666670072860103508101\n"
      ."0100008030950106200270002020139450000000020000006663540105338500\n"
      ."0100004586400106200270002020206660000000003700000511890102603900\n"
      ."0100008204530106200270002020218320000000011666670014450101008906\n"
      ."0100015309660106200270002021023010000000019400001666460105319807\n";

if( preg_match_all('#^\d{6}#m',$str,$matches) ){
  echo join("\n",$matches[0]);
}
```

Result:

```
010001
010000
010000
010000
010001
```

Answer (score 5):

Introducing [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok)

```
$text = <<<EOM
0100014746510106200140001020061780000000041666670072860103508101
0100008030950106200270002020139450000000020000006663540105338500
0100004586400106200270002020206660000000003700000511890102603900
0100008204530106200270002020218320000000011666670014450101008906
0100015309660106200270002021023010000000019400001666460105319807
EOM;

for ($line = strtok($text, "\n"); $line !== false; $line = strtok("\n")) {
        echo substr($line, 0, 6), "\n";
}
```

The function `strtok()` chunks your string based on a token (or delimiter); in this code, each line is a chunk and for each chunk you only show the first six characters followed by a newline.

**Update**

You can also use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.{6}).*/m', '$1', $text);
```

It captures the first six characters, followed by the rest of the line; it then uses the memory capture to perform the replacement.

Comment: Probably the best solution since it doesn't require creating a new data structure to copy the data into, thus consuming memory.

Answer (score 3):

#### NOTE - Of all of the posted correct answers this is probably the most memory inefficient but hey, it's a one-liner.

Just to throw in a one-liner (will work on php 5.3 and above). This assumes your input is $str and lines will contain a newline separated string of the first 6 characters of each line.

```
$lines = implode("\n", array_map(function($a){return substr($a, 0, 6); }, explode("\n",$str)));
```

Comment: But now it's an array ;-)

Comment: Better; pity about the string -> array -> string conversions though :)

Comment: @Jack I already upvoted your and concede that it is the better solution...  enough beating up my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

basically:

```
$x=explode("\n",$result); //new line will depend on os ("\r\n"|"\r")

foreach($x as $line){
//substr $line
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... I will surely try this and get back if this works thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
$str = explode(PHP_EOL, "
        0100014746510106200140001020061780000000041666670072860103508101 
        0100008030950106200270002020139450000000020000006663540105338500 
        0100004586400106200270002020206660000000003700000511890102603900 
        0100008204530106200270002020218320000000011666670014450101008906 
        0100015309660106200270002021023010000000019400001666460105319807
");
for($i = 0; $i<count($str);$i++){
    if($str[$i] != NULL)
        echo substr((string)$str[$i],0,9);
}
?>
```

PHP_EOL =>
The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

[PHP : Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

You can also use '\r\n' if PHP_EOL is not available.

Comment: you should always do the count outside the loop structure

Comment: thanks for the reply... I will surely try this and get back if this works thanks

Comment: Splitting on `PHP_EOL` is not always portable.

Comment: I don't know why substr($str[$i], 0, 6) didn't work. 0, 9 is working.